# UNITY 2D - How to add RectTransform.height without affecting it's Y position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What's happening:
[image]

Everytime I add value to height.. the 'top-most' area is causing to mess-up the y.position of the gameObject.

The **GOAL** is: 
[image]

How to achieve this kind of approach/behavior via script that makes the 'top-most' area stay?

**Thank you in advance. Best regards.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to set the Y-value of the Pivot on your Rect Transform to 1.0 (top).
Then when you increase the Height, it will grow relative to the pivot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The default `anchoredPosition` is in the center by default. You'll need to set it to the upper left corner. There is a sample code shown [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-anchoredPosition.html)